# Sum Quantity in Mongo Subdocument Based on Filter

Tags: database, mongodb, filter, aggregation

I have a "shipment" document in MongoDB that has the following basic structure:

```
shipment {
   "id": "asdfasdfasdf",
   "shipDate": "2021-04-02",
   "packages": [
        {
            "id": "adfasdfasdfasdf",
            "contents": [
                {
                    "product": {
                        "id": "asdfasdfasdfasd"
                    },
                    "quantity": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

*Please note that "product" is stored as a DBRef.*

I want to find the total quantity of a specific product (based on the product ID) that has been shipped since a given date. I believe this is the appropriate logic that should be followed:

1. Match shipments with "shipDate" greater than the given date.
2. Find entries where "contents" contains a product with an "id" matching the given product ID
3. Sum the "quantity" value for each matching entry
4. Return the sum

So far, this is what I've come up with for the Mongo query so far:

```
db.shipment.aggregate([
    {$match: {"shipDate": {$gt: ISODate("2019-01-01")}}},
    {$unwind: "$packages"},
    {$unwind: "$packages.contents"},
    {$unwind: "$packages.contents.product"},
    {
        $project: {
            matchedProduct: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$packages.contents.products",
                    as: "products",
                    cond: { 
                        "$eq": ["$products.id", ObjectId("5fb55eae3fb1bf783a4fa97f")]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The query works, but appears to just return all entries that meet the $match criteria with a "products" value of null.

I'm pretty new with Mongo queries, so it may be a simple solution. However, I've been unable to figure out just how to return the $sum of the "contents" quantity fields for a matching product ID.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

**Query Which Solved The Problem**

```
db.shipment.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "shipDate": {$gte: ISODate("2019-01-01")},
      "packages.contents.product.$id": ObjectId("5fb55eae3fb1bf783a4fa98e")
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$packages" },
  { $unwind: "$packages.contents" },
  { $unwind: "$packages.contents.product" },
  {
    $match: {
      "packages.contents.product.$id": ObjectId("5fb55eae3fb1bf783a4fa98e")
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$packages.contents.quantity"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/c3Ia9L47cJS

Use `{ $match: {"packages.contents.product.id": 1 } },` to filter records by product id.

After that group them back and find the total `{ $group: {"_id": null,"total": { "$sum": "$packages.contents.quantity" } } }`

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: {"shipDate": "2021-04-02","packages.contents.product.id": 1 } },
  { $unwind: "$packages" },
  { $unwind: "$packages.contents" },
  { $match: { "packages.contents.product.id": 1 } },
  { $group: { "_id": null,"total": { "$sum": "$packages.contents.quantity" } } }
])
```

---

Adding extra check at top `{ $match: {"shipDate": "2021-04-02","packages.contents.product.id": 1 } }` for product id will filter only documents with produce id we need so query will be faster.

---

**Option-2**

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/eo521luylsG

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "shipDate": "2021-04-02", "packages.contents.product.id": 1 }},
  { $unwind: "$packages" },
  { $project: { contents: { $filter: { input: "$packages.contents", as: "contents",  cond: {"$eq": [  "$$contents.product.id",  1] }}}}},
  { $unwind: "$contents" },
  { $group: { "_id": null,  "total": { "$sum": "$contents.quantity" }}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I gave it a shot with my application and the query works but does not return anything despite the product.id I am searching for being present in the contents array. I believe this is being caused by the product being stored as a DBRef. 
Example: 
`
"contents" : [ { "product" : DBRef("product", ObjectId("5fb55eae3fb1bf783a4fa982")), "quantity" : 36 } ]`

Is there a special syntax that needs to be used to match product.id when it is a DBRef?

Comment: @Kylep5587 Can you please add your sample data on https://mongoplayground.net/ and share the link,

Comment: @Kylep5587  Try `"packages.contents.product.$id"` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/

Comment: I tried switching to $id, but it still doesn't match any documents. Here is a link to the sample data on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/MA1CTnGJJyP.

Comment: Check @Kylep5587 https://mongoplayground.net/p/v55ACicLQMZ in your sample you didn't have `packages` key and `contents.product.id` is of type `ObjectId`.

Comment: I forgot to add packages when I was entering my sample data. I adjusted it and was able to make this work using your suggestions and adding in a `{ $unwind: "$packages" }` just above the unwind for contents. Thanks for all the help!